# How to create appRoles with azurerm provider on terraform

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform

I'm trying to setup my azure infrastructure using Terraform which was pretty successful so far. Our app development team needs to define application specific roles within the AzureAD application's manifest which we currently handling with the Azure Portal by simply modifying the manifest:

```
"appRoles": [
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "Application"
        ],
        "displayName": "SurveyCreator",
        "id": "1b4f816e-5eaf-48b9-8613-7923830595ad",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "description": "Creators can create Surveys",
        "value": "SurveyCreator"
    }
]
```

Using Terraform I created an `azurerm_azuread_application` and now want to modify the manifest accordingly.

```
resource "azurerm_azuread_application" "test" {
  name                       = "APP"
  homepage                   = "http://APPHOMEPAGE"
  identifier_uris            = ["http://APPHOMEPAGE"]
  reply_urls                 = ["http://APPHOMEPAGE/REPLYURL"]
  available_to_other_tenants = false
  oauth2_allow_implicit_flow = false
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this by using Terraform only?

Answer (score 1):

To create the App role, you could refer to [`azuread_application_app_role`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application_app_role).

```
resource "azuread_application" "example" {
  name = "example"
}

resource "azuread_application_app_role" "example" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.example.id
  allowed_member_types  = ["User"]
  description           = "Admins can manage roles and perform all task actions"
  display_name          = "Admin"
  is_enabled            = true
  value                 = "administer"
}
```